# Amchart Sankey 4 height handling

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, sankey-diagram, amcharts4

I have an issue that when I tried to increase the height of amchart container, the nodes get bigger and somehow the content is out of the container and get hidden. I tried maxHeight for fox node and container but seems doesn't help much.

Here is without container specific height
[image: Here is without container specific height]

Here is with 2000px fixed height
[image: Here is with 2000px fixed height]

Here is some settings

```
chart.padding(0, 10, 10, 0);
chart.nodePadding = 20; // Default is 20
chart.nodeMinSize = 0.1;
chart.maxHeight = 1000;
chart.nodes.template.height = 10;
chart.nodes.template.maxHeight = 12;
chart.links.template.height = 10;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with `backbone.js`?

Comment: I guess not but I used with backbone so there might be chance. Just in case.